# How to set php directives on a remote server?

Tags: php

My question is very simple. I'm working on a local PHP Project.
I set my php.ini with some custom configurations.

Later i will host the project in a commercial host provider.

However that remote server will have it´s own PHP configurations, and my custom php.ini directives will have no effect. Am I right?

If so, how can I use my custom php.ini in a remote server?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have access to the .ini file, just copy your local version to the remote host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a good number of options using `ini_set` – but of course, a fair number of those might not really be available to change on your hosting provider. But things like `error_reporting`, `display_errors` can be set.

Depending on the configuration and version your hosting provider uses, you might have the option to set php_options in the htaccess file (if they use `mod_php`-based hosting, which I take to be a little less common these days), or in a `.user.ini` file in the directory that your php code resides in. But that's entirely up to the webhosting place.

Answer (score 2):

With something like this, you have modified your php.ini; in standard web hosting you will not have access to modify the php.ini as that one file is in use by all users of the hosting company.

For you to have full control over your php.ini you will need to go over to a VPS/Dedicated server and configure a Lamp server. From that you can make the same changes you did on your local server

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your server configuration.

On most shared server providers, you won't be able to mess with php.ini; in VPS / dedicated environment you can edit settings, but you should ask your provider about of course.

Answer (score 0):

First, your **local** `php.ini` has **no effect** on the server one, you are correct.

Now, configuring the **remote** `php.ini` depends on what kind of hosting do you have. 
With shared hosting, there usually aren't many things you could configure, but if you have a **VPS**(Virtual Private Server) or **dedicated** server, you should be able to copy/paste it.

Also, keep in mind, that if you don't have many custom configurations, some little tweaks, can bo done via PHP itself.